# I am having a hard time seeing how this equality works in calculating the coefficent in a regression of y on x.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-regression

[Confusing equality for the regression coefficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkSa8.png)

Comment: Expand the products, express the averages as sums and regroup the terms.

Comment: "Works" is a bit vague. That could mean you don't know what the notation means or you don't see how it represents a regression coefficient. Maybe other possibilities too.

Comment: By works I mean I just don't understand the algebra. How do you get from the left side to the right side of that equality?

Answer (score 1):

For the numerator, you obtain after expanding the products as recommended by Yves
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_n (x_n-\overline{x})(y_n-\overline{y})
&=&
\sum_n x_n y_n - \overline{y} \sum_n x_n - \overline{x} \sum_n y_n + N \overline{x} \overline{y} \\
&=&
\sum_n x_n y_n 
- \left(\frac{\sum_n y_n}{N}\right) \sum_n x_n 
- \left(\frac{\sum_n x_n}{N}\right) \sum_n y_n 
+ N \left(\frac{\sum_n x_n}{N}\right)\left(\frac{\sum_n y_n}{N}\right) \\
&=&
\sum_n x_n y_n - \frac{1}{N} \left(\sum_n x_n\right) \left(\sum_n y_n\right)
\end{eqnarray}
The denominator proceeds identically if you replace $y$ by $x$

Comment: Yes I totally see it now. Thank you. Should have been able to figure that one out myself! Working in the reverse direction is less intuitive.